# Table Break on RDLC Report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, reporting, rdlc

I have created RDLC Report, Below is image

[image]

But When I am printing this report, the table break. I want this table should continue to end of the page then it should break.
Below is image of PDF, how it is printing

[image]

Please share your suggestion.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Tablix properties, the `PageBreak` setting could be the issue.

[image]